# Proof of the polynomial division algorithm

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, induction

The theorem which I am referring to states: for any $f, g$ there exist $q, r$ such that $f(x)=g(x)q(x)+r(x)$ with the degree of $r$ less than the degree of $g$ if $g$ is monic.

The book I am using remarks that it can be proven via induction on the degree of $g$, but leaves the proof to the reader. Unfortunately, this reader is not clever enough to get it.

The base case is fairly clear, but I'm completely stuck after that. Any hints?

Comment: Huh. I would induct on the degree of $f$ instead. (By the way, to me "the division algorithm" also includes the statement that $q, r$ are unique.)

Comment: Oh - I assumed induction of degree of $f$ as well. I suppose they aren't really too different, but $f$ seems much more natural.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT:

Prove that in an integral domain, if $f$ and $g$ are nonzero polynomials then $\deg(fg) = \deg(f) + \deg(g)$. Then, once you have the base case and are working with the induction hypothesis, write out the polynomials. That is, $f = a_n x^n + a_{n-2} x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_0$, $g = b_m x^m + \cdots + b_0$. Multiply $g$ by an appropriate multiple of a power of $x$ and subtract. Use the induction hypothesis.

Does that make sense?

Comment: The ring needn't be a domain. In any ring one can divide (with remainder) by *monic* divisors.

Comment: To make Bill's claim more clear, the proof works as long as $b_m$ is invertible in $R$. But even if $R$ is an integral domain, the second part of the proof doesn't work if $b_m$ is not invertible.

Answer (score 19):

**Hint** $ $ If $\, f- g\,h\, $ has $\,\deg \ge g\,$ then subtracting $\, \color{#c00}{c\:\!x^k}\:\!g\ $ (choose $\,\color{#c00}c\,$  to kill lead coef of $\:\!f)$ yields a *smaller* degree polynomial of same form $\, f - g\, h'.\, $ Note: this inducts on $\,\deg f,\,$ not on $\,\deg g$.

The **key idea** of [polynomial division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) is this: if the divisor has *invertible* lead coef $\,b\,$ (e.g. $\,b=1)\,$ and the dividend has degree $\ge$ the divisor, then we can  $\rm\color{#c00}{scale}$ the divisor so that it has the same degree and leading coef as the dividend, then subtract it from the dividend, thereby killing the leading term of the dividend; then recursively apply this process to the remaining part of the dividend, which has *smaller degree* (since we killed the lead term of the dividend), viz.

$$\begin{align}  (\overbrace{a x^{\large k+n} + f}^{\large \rm dividend})\ -\  &\color{#c00}{\frac{a}b x^{\large k}} (\overbrace{b x^{\large n} + g}^{\large \rm divisor})\ =\ \overbrace{\color{#0a0}{f-\frac{a}b x^kg}}^{\large {\rm deg}\ <\ k+n}\\[.4em]
\Longrightarrow\ \ \ \dfrac{a x^{\large k+n}+f}{bx^{\large n}+g}\, =\ &\color{#c00}{\frac{a}b x^{\large k}}\ \ +\  \underbrace{\dfrac{\color{#0a0}{f-\frac{a}bx^{\large k} g}}{bx^n + g}}_{\large\rm recurse\ on\ this}\end{align}\qquad\qquad$$

$$\require{enclose}
\begin{array}{r}
                \color{#c00}{\frac{a}b\:\! x^k}\phantom{x^{k+n}+f\ }\,\ \   \\[0pt]
{\Large \smash[t]{\overset{\rm\color{#90f}{tabularly}}{\leadsto^{\phantom{.}}}}}\quad\  bx^n\!+g\,\ \enclose{longdiv}{\,\ a x^{k+n}\,+\,f\phantom{x^kg}} \\[-3pt]
                  \underline{ax^{k+n}\, +\, \frac{a}b x^k g} \\
                                  \color{#0a0}{f\,-\,\frac{a}b x^k g}  
\end{array}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad$$

where the second equation arises from the first by dividing through by $\,bx^n + g. \,$ The final expression displayed above shows how this single division step is represented in the common $\rm\color{#90f}{table\ form}.\,$ This single division (descent) step is iterated till we reach a dividend that has smaller degree than the divisor (which must occur since $\Bbb N$ is well-ordered; equivalently, we can use a proof by [*strong* induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_(strong)_induction)).

Rephrased in the language of Gaussian elimination: $\,b\,$ being invertible in the lead monomial $\,b\:\!x^n\,$ of the divisor means we can use it as a *pivot* to scale-up and eliminate all higher degree monomials. This [pivoting viewpoint](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/14225/242) will become clearer when one studies multivariate division algorithms (standard (Grobner) ideal bases and monomial orderings) which are *nonlinear* generalizations of Gaussian elimination, and [unification algorithms](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/15854/242) for (equational) term rewriting systems.

**Remark** $ $ This method works $\rm\color{#0a0}{universally}$ to kill the lead coef of the dividend when the lead coef of the divisor $\,g\,$ is a unit (invertible) so it is a divisor of $\rm\color{#0a0}{every}$ coefficient, so it is always possible to scale it to agree with the lead coef of the divisor. Otoh, if the lead coef of the divisor is *not* a unit then this is not always possible, e.g. consider $\, x \div 2x\:$ in $\rm\,\mathbb Z[x]\!:\: $ if $\,x = (2x)q(x) + c\,$ then evaluating at $\,x=0\Rightarrow c=0,\,$ therefore cancelling $\,x\,$ yields that $\,1 = 2q(x)\,$ thus, again, evaluating at $\,x = 0\Rightarrow 1 = 2q(0)\Rightarrow 2\mid 1\,$ in $\Bbb Z,\,$ contradiction [cf. [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2523/242) that $\,x\nmid 1\,$ in $R[x]$].

We can generalize the polynomial division algorithm to divisors with noninvertible lead coefs, e.g.

**Theorem** (nonmonic Polynomial Division Algorithm) $\ $ Let $\,0\neq F,G\in A[x]\,$ be polynomials over a comm. ring $A,$ with $\,a\,$ = lead coef of $\,F,\,$ and $\, i \ge \max\{0,\,1+\deg G-\deg F\}.\,$ Then
$\qquad\qquad \phantom{1^{1^{1^{1^{1^{1}}}}}}a^{i} G\, =\, Q F + R\ \ {\rm for\ some}\ \  Q,R\in A[x],\ \deg R < \deg F$

**Proof** $\ $ [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/116037/242) for a few proofs.

There are also multivariate generalizations of the polynomial division algorithm such as the  [Gröbner basis algorithm.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grobner_basis) One gains further insight from this more general perspective on the descent process, e.g. in terms of [monomial orderings.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial_order)

Comment: Could you give me an explanation of this: *then recursively apply this process to the remaining part of the dividend, which has smaller degree (since we killed the lead term of the dividend)*?

Comment: @John We recurse on the new underbraced "smaller" quotient,  i.e. our new dividend is the numerator $\,\color{#0a0}{f-\frac{a}b x^k g}\,$ which has smaller degree than the original dividend. See the edit above where I show the corresponding $\rm\color{#90f}{tabular}$ form.

Comment: @user161005 A coef $\,b\,$ is invertible means that there is some coef $\,c\,$ such that $\,bc = 1,\,$ i.e. $\,b\,$ is a unit (invertible) in the coefficient ring, e.g. for polynomials over a field like $\Bbb Q,\,\Bbb R,\Bbb C\,$ all nonzero coef's are invertible, but over $\Bbb Z$ only $\pm1$ are invertible since, e.g. $2$ isn't invertible in the coef ring $\Bbb Z$ since there is no $\,n\in\Bbb Z\,$ such that $\,2n = 1.\ \ $

Comment: How did you get this?: https://i.imgur.com/EupiXb6.png

Comment: @user161005 As explained, we want to scale the divisor $\,bx^n+g\,$  by some $\,\color{#c00}{cx^j}\,$ to  make it have the same $\rm\color{#0a0}{lead\  term}$ as the dividend $\,\color{#0a0}{ax^{k+n}} + f$, i.e. so $\,\color{#0a0}{ax^{k+n}} = (cx^j)(bx^n) = \color{#c00}cb x^{\color{#c00}j+n},\,$ so $\,\color{#c00}j = \color{#0a0}k,\ \color{#c00}c = \color{#0a0}a/b\,$ yields the sought scaling term  $\,\color{#c00}{\frac{a}b x^k}\ \ $

Comment: what a great answer. @BillDubuque thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much for this wonderful argument. I am familiar with (and have produced) the argument by strong induction to which you alluded but my text proceeds hand-wavily with the "recursive descent" method which you also mention. Would it be possible to explain how to rigorize this (or point me to a source which does) if you get the chance? Thank you!

Comment: @EE18 The sketched recursive algorithm is simply a constructive interpretation of the inductive proof.

Comment: I think I only half see what you are saying; are you saying that there really is one argument or that there are two? Because mine, during the strong induction step, only uses one "reduction of degree" step and then appeals to the induction hypothesis. Is there another version which basically starts with any degree and then reduces over and over and which rigorously shows this process terminates (you mentioned WOP in this respect). If so, I guess this is what I am wondering about if at all possible. I am also happy to post my proof as a separate question if easier or if you prefer.

Comment: @EE18 They are essentially the same - simply replace "recurse" above by "induct". Algorithmic interpretations of constructive strong induction proofs yield recursive functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a relatively tricky proof from linear algebra done right (but actually not tricky at all).
We are aiming to express a polynomial of degree n by two other polynomials with lower degree, n-m for p and m-1 for q seperately, so why not consider the linear spaces Pn-m(F)*Pm-1(F) and Pn(F). T(p,q)=pg+q is obviously a linear map between the two spaces, and it's trivial to check that it's an isomorphism.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)