# Calculations in polynomial quotient rings e.g. $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2+1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, soft-question

Is there a nice way to perform calculations within a quotient ring? for instance, an exercise I had was to show $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2+1) \cong \mathbb{Z}[i]$, but this got me thinking; If I didn't know this, how could I calculate in $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2+1)$ easily?  (and of course any other general quotient ring)?

Comment: What are the elements of $\mathbb Z[X]/(X^2+1)$?

Comment: @JPLF Well, the example was just that.. this case isn't so bad. $X^2+1\in (X^2+1) \implies [X^2+1]=[0]\implies [x^2]=[-1]$ and from there you can deal with the powers of x nicely, to find that the elements are of the form $\alpha + \beta X$ for $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{Z}$. But y'know.. working with the equivalence classes resulting from the ideal used probably isn't always so nice.

Comment: How did you manage to show that $\mathbf{Z}[X]/\langle X^2+1\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}[i]$ if you can't compute in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+1)$ you can simply calculate as in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ on representants of equivalence classes and then, if you need it, reduce them applying polynomial division by $x^2+1$ and keeping the remainder. The only "complicated" operation is to check if two elements $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ and  are equal, for which you must show (again using polynomial division) that
$$p(x)-q(x)\equiv 0\mod{x^2+1}$$

Answer (score 2):

Modular polynomial arithmetic is analogous to modular integer arithmetic since, in both cases, we have available an (Euclidean) algorithm for [Division with Smaller Remainder.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) This allows us to efficiently calculate canonical normal-form reps of cosets, viz. those of least size, i.e. remainders.

If $R$ is a ring and $\,f\in R[x]\,$ has lead coeff $1$ (or any *invertible*) then we can [divide](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/767467/242) by $f$ with [unique remainder:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/168853/242) for  $\,g\in R[x]\,$ there are $\,q,r\in R[x]\,$ with $\,g = q f + r,\,$ with $\,\deg r < \deg f.\,$  Said equivalently, $\,r\,$ is the least degree element of the coset $\,g + fR[x]$ in the quotient ring $\,S = R[x]/f.\, $ This easily implies that a complete system of reps for the quotient ring $S$ are all such remainders mod $\,f,\,$ which is clearly the set of all polynomials of smaller degree than $\,f.$

Then, just [like in $\,\Bbb Z/m,\,$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3910465/242) we [transport the ring structure](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/190326/242) to this set of normal reps, e.g. to calculate the product of two reps, we multiply them as elements of $\,R[x]$ then reduce the result $\,{\rm mod}\ f\,$ to obtain the least degree rep of the product, i.e. $\,g * h = (g h\,\ {\rm mod}\,\ f).\,$ For example, in your ring $\,\Bbb Z[x]/(x^2\!+1)\,$ our reps are all $\, a+bx,\,$ for all $\,a,b\in \Bbb Z,\,$ with product $(a\!+\!bx) * (c\!+\!dx)\,$ being

$$\begin{eqnarray} {\rm mod}\,\ x^2\!+1\!:\ \  (a\!+\!bx)\,(c\!+\!dx) \,&=&\, ac + \color{#c00}{bd\,x^2}\! &+& (ad\!+\!bc)\,x \\ \,&\equiv&\, ac \color{#c00}{- bd} &+& (ad\!+\!bc)\,x,\ \ {\rm by}\ \ \color{#c00}{x^2\equiv -1}\\
\Rightarrow \ \ (a\!+\!bx)*(c\!+\!dx) \,&=&\,  ac-bd &+& (ad\!+\!bc)\,x\\
\end{eqnarray}$$

This is just the usual rule for multiplication of complex numbers, once we rename $\,x\,$ to $\:i.\,$

This normal form rewriting using the polynomial division algorithm  generalizes to multivariate rings over nice coefficient rings (e.g. fields, Euclidean domains) - see the [Gröbner basis algorithm.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis)