# A question about the division algorithm of polynomials.

Tags: abstract-algebra

My Algebra book (Fraleigh) says the following:

> Let $f$ and $g$ be two polynomials. If the leading term of $g$ divides the leading term of $f$, then we can execute a division of $f$ by $g$.

Why is division only then possible? What about $f=x^3+xy^2+1$ and $g=y^2+2$? We can surely write $x^3+xy^2+1=x(y^2+2)+(x^3-2x+1)$

Is it that division is possible only when the degree of the remainder is strictly lower than that of the dividend?

Comment: Is an implication not an if and only if (sufficient but not necessary)

Comment: Maybe Fraleigh is only talking about polynomials in one variable. Or maybe he is talking about division in which the remainder is smaller, in some well-defined sense, than the divisor. You have left out all the context.

Comment: In your example, leading coefficients of $f$ and $g$ were both $1$...

Answer (score 4):

The point is that when that condition holds then one can scale $g$ to make its leading term equal to the leading term of $f$, so subtracting the two yields $f'\!$ with smaller degree, and $\,f'\equiv f\pmod g.\,$ In particular, when the leading coefficient of $g$ is $1$ (or a unit = invertible) then this is always possible so iterating this reduction we eventually obtain a polynomial of degree smaller than $g$, i.e. this yields an algorithm to compute the remainder of $f$ on division by $g$, the Polynomial Division Algorithm.

---

The key idea of the [polynomial division algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) is this: if the leading coefficient of the divisor $= 1$ (or is invertible), and the dividend has degree $\ge$ the divisor, then we can  $\rm\color{#c00}{scale}$ the divisor so that it has the same degree and leading coef as the dividend, then subtract it from the dividend, thereby canceling the leading term of the dividend; then recursively apply this process to the remaining part of the dividend, which has *smaller degree* (since we killed the leading term of the dividend), viz.

$$  (\overbrace{a x^{k+n} + f}^{\large \rm dividend}) - \color{#c00}{a x^k} (\overbrace{x^n + g}^{\large \rm divisor})\ =\ \overbrace{\color{#0a0}{f-ax^kg}}^{\large {\rm deg}\ <\ k+n}\qquad\qquad$$

$$\ \Rightarrow\ \ \dfrac{a x^{k+n}+f}{x^n+g}\, =\ \color{#c00}{a x^k} +\!\!\! \underbrace{\dfrac{f-ax^k g}{x^n + g}}_{\large\rm recurse\ on\ this}\qquad\qquad\qquad$$

where the second equation arises from the first by dividing through by $\,x^n + g.\,$ The long division algorithm for polynomials is simply a convenient tabular arrangement of the process obtained by iterating this descent process till one reaches a dividend that has smaller degree than the divisor (which must occur since $\Bbb N$ is well-ordered; alternatively, we can use a proof by [*strong* induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_(strong)_induction)).

**Remark** $ $ Polynomial division can be generalizaed to non-monic polynomials as follows

**Theorem** (nonmonic Polynomial Division Algorithm) $\ $ Let $\,0\neq F,G\in A[x]\,$ be polynomials over a commutative ring $A,$ with $\,a\,$ = lead coef of $\,F,\,$ and $\, i \ge \max\{0,\,1+\deg G-\deg F\}.\,$ Then
$\qquad\qquad \phantom{1^{1^{1^{1^{1^{1}}}}}}a^{i} G\, =\, Q F + R\ \ {\rm for\ some}\ \  Q,R\in A[x],\ \deg R < \deg F$

**Proof** $\ $ [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/116037/242) for a few proofs.

There are also multivariate generalizations of the polynomial division algorithm such as the  [Gröbner basis algorithm.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grobner_basis) One gains further insight from this more general perspective on the descent process, e.g. in terms of [monomial orderings.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial_order)

Comment: excellent and interesting explanation