# What is the term for a modular arithmetic problem involving quotients and remainders of functions?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, soft-question

I saw one of my middle school students working on a problem that went something like this:

> When $f(x)$ is divided by $x - \frac{1}{2}$, the quotient is $Q(x)$
>   and the remainder is $R$. What are the quotient and remainder,
>   respectively, when $x f(x)$ is divided by $2x-1$?

Then you had to choose between several answers, each in terms of $Q(x)$ and $R$.

What do you call this kind of problem, and how can I learn how to solve things like this? I never saw anything like this when I did elementary math.  For the integer case, it seems like you could use the [quotient-remainder theorem](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/the-quotient-remainder-theorem), but I don't know how to generalize that to the function case.

Searching for "quotient-remainder theorem with functions" and such has gotten me nowhere.

Comment: try searching with "polynomials" instead of "functions"

Comment: See also [Euclidean domains,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain) and for higher-dimensional (multivariate) division algorithms see the literature on [Grobner / standard basis algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis)

Comment: Thanks @J.W.Tanner. The trick in this problem is to then use polynomial division.

Comment: @Max Polynomial division is presumed known, cf. "when $f$ is divided by $\,x - 1/2\,$" so that's not the trick, Rather it's simply to *scale* the division by $x$ then $1/2,\,$ - see my answer.

Comment: @BillDubuque I used polynomial division to divide $x f(x) = x(Q(x) (x - 1/2) + R) = x^2 Q(x) - x (-1/2 + R)$ by $2x - 1$. This got me the correct answer without needing to know an external algorithm.

Comment: @Max We don't need to do any *further* division - it suffices to scale the original division $\ f\div (x-1/2),\,$ as I explained in my answer. That way clarifies the innate *arithmetic*, i.e. we are multiplying (scaling) it by $\,x\equiv 1/2.\ $ It seems you are essentially doing the same thing (but I can't be sure since you didn't give details).

Answer (score 1):

It's the [Polynomial Division Algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/767467/242). The solution involves only scaling that: $\ (a=\frac{1}2$ in OP)

$$\begin{align} \dfrac{f}{x-a} &\,=\, q + \dfrac{r}{x-a}\\[.4em]
 \Rightarrow\ \ \dfrac{xf}{x-a} &\,=\, xq + \dfrac{xr}{x-a}\\[.4em]
 &\,=\, xq + \dfrac{(x-a)r + ar}{x-a}\\[.4em]
 &\,=\, xq+r + \dfrac{\color{#c00}{ar}}{x-a}\\[.4em]
\Rightarrow\ \ \dfrac{xf}{2(x-a)}&\, =\, \tfrac{1}2(xq+r)  + \dfrac{\color{}{ar}}{2(x-a)}
\end{align}\qquad$$

**Simpler**  by congruences: $\bmod x\!-\!a\!:\ \ \begin{align}x\equiv a\\ f\equiv  r\end{align}\  \Rightarrow\ xf\equiv \color{#c00}{ar}\ $ by the [Congruence Product Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)