# Cardinality of the ring $F_3[x] / (x^2-x+1)$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, galois-theory

How would I find the number of elements of the ring $F_3[x] / (x^2-x+1)$?

I know that $x^2-x+1$ is not prime/irreducible, since gcd($x^2-x+1$, $x^3-x^2-1$) = 3.

Can anyone provide some tips?

Comment: Hint: see the second paragraph of [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1145277/242)

Comment: Great answer Bill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not relevant if the polynomial is irreducible or not to find the number of elements of the ring.

Given a non-constant polynomial $g$ and a field $F$, we have $F[X]/(g)$ is an $F$-vectorspace of dimension $\deg g$.

As such its cardinality is $|F|^{\deg g}$.

(If you want to say something on the multiplicative structure of the ring, then the factorization gets important.)

Comment: The degree of g is 2 right? What is |F|?

Comment: Yes the degree is $2$ and $|F|$ is the cardinality of your field $F_3$, which should be $3$.

Comment: Ah I see!! Thanks quid.