# If $R=K[X]/(X^n)$, can represent any element as polynomial with degree $<n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, equivalence-relations, quotient-spaces

Let $K$ be a field and $R=K[X]/(X^n)$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{n\geq1}$ and $(X^n)$ is the ideal generated by $X^n$. We denote $x:=X+(X^n) \in R$, **any equivalence class $r$ in $R$ has a representing element of the form:** $$r=a_0+a_1X+ \dots + a_{n-1}X^{n-1}.$$

I am confused about the statement in bold. How would I find such an element for $X^3 \in K[X]$ if $n=2$ for example?

Comment: Hint: Use Euclidean division in $k[x]$.

Comment: $X^3$ is allowed by that form. Unless I misunderstand your question.

Comment: Sorry! I edited it to include $n=2$

Comment: When you quotient by $(X^n)$ you're effectively saying any time you see $X^n$ you can replace the term with 0. So all terms of degree $\geq n$ will vanish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the [Division Algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/116037/242) $\ f = q\, x^n + r\ $ with $\,\deg r < n,\,$ hence $\,f\equiv r\pmod{\!x^n}$

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1145277/242) for further discussion of such normal forms in quotient of Euclidean domains.

Same for $R[x]/g$ over any commutative ring $R$ and any polynomial $g$ whose leading coeff is a *unit* (invertible), since this enables division with smaller (degree) remainder (as explained in the links).

Answer (score 1):

$K[X]$ is a $K$-vector space with basis
$$1, X, X^2, X^3,\dots$$
Making the quotient by $(X^n)$, you are killing all elements of the basis of degree $\geq n$, getting a basis for $R$ which is simply $1, X,X^2, \dots, X^{n-1} \ \  (+(X^n))$.

So, a polynomial $\sum_k a_k X^k$ is transformed by killing all terms of degree $\geq n$, becoming $\sum_{k \leq n-1}a_kX^k$. In you particular example, $X^3$ becomes $0$.