# The ring $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{\langle x^n \rangle}$ is isomorphic to?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, ring-homomorphism, ring-isomorphism

It is an easy exercise to show that $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[z]}{\langle x \rangle }$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ using the fundamental theorem of ring homomorphisms.

I was wondering if the quotient ring $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[z]}{\langle x^2 \rangle }$ is isomorphic to a simpler ring or not?

More generally, can we simplify $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[z]}{\langle x^n \rangle }$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ ?

I tried attempting this using a similar approach as for $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[z]}{\langle x \rangle }$ but I am unable to find a homomorphism for which $Ker(\phi) = \langle x^n \rangle$.

Any help/hints will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You probably mean $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{\langle x \rangle }$ instead of $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[z]}{\langle x \rangle }$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure whether it is a simpler description, but $\Bbb Z[X]/(X^n)$ is isomorphic to the ring of matrices with entries in $\Bbb Z$ of the form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_0& a_1 & a_2 & \dotsm & a_{n-1}\\
0 & a_0 & a_1 & \dotsm & a_{n-2} \\
0 & 0 & a_0 &\dotsm & a_{n-3} \\
\vdots& \vdots &\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 &0 &0 & \dotsm & a_0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
For $n = 2$, this is the ring of matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\ 0&a\end{pmatrix}$, with $a, b \in \Bbb Z$.

Comment: Yes! That's definitely simpler.

Comment: @Ano It's very puzzling why you find this simpler than the  set of [remainder  normal forms](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1163430/242) (all $f\in \Bbb Z[x]\,$ with $\deg f < n),\,$ i.e. the least degree reps $\!\bmod x^n$. Note that this matrix rep is simply the [(left) regular rep](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95208/242), i.e. view $f$ as a linear scaling map $\, g\mapsto fg$, which has the above matrix w.r.t. basis $1,x,x^2,\ldots, x^{n-1}.\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

Its isomorphic to the ring of polynomials $\{a_0+a_1x+\ldots+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}\mid a_i\in\Bbb Z\}$ with $x^n=0$.