# Can someone please explain WHY synthetic division works?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know how to do synthetic division, but I do not understand why it works.

Comment: Compare it with long division. All of the intermediate numbers should show up in both.

Comment: Ok. But I don't really understand how ling division works with polynomials

Comment: Synthetic division is just a nice way of writing long division (you're basically omitting the $x$'s, and ignoring the terms you already know will cancel.) In order to understand why it works, you first need to understand how and why long division works.

Comment: Do you understand ordinary long division? It's hard to write up long division problems here.

Comment: Yes. I understand ordinary long division. But not with polynomials

Comment: might help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/171191/why-does-synthetic-division-work?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Lets see a simple example:

$$x+1|x^2+2x+1$$

In order to do this using long polynomial division we do:

$$
  \begin{array}{rl}
    \underline{x+1\phantom{00000}} & \hbox{} \\[-5pt]
    x + 1 | x^2+2x+1 \\
      \underline{x^2+x\phantom{)))))}} & \hbox{($x \times x+1 = x^2+x$)} \\
      x+1\phantom{} & \hbox{($(x^2 + 2x)- (x^2+x) = x$)} \\
      \underline{\phantom{0}x+1\phantom{}} & \hbox{($(x+1)-(x+1) = 0$)} \\
      \phantom{0}0 
  \end{array}
$$

When we synthetic division we don't put in the x's to simplify it. (I want to do the synthetic division here but it takes really long to type)