# How to prove the "division algorithm"?

Tags: algorithms, proof-explanation, arithmetic

I put "division algorithm" but what I actually mean is the algorithm for dividing large numbers (I couldn't find the English name for it). Let's say we want to divide $3283$ by $38$ without a help of machines. We would check the whole part of $\frac{328}{38}$, then subtract it from $328$, then repeat it until we "arrive" at $0$. But how do we prove that this algorithm is correct? My main issue is in the underlined place from the picture below:
[image]

Comment: Closely related: [who invented division and why we do division in those steps told?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683774/who-invented-division-and-why-we-do-division-in-those-steps-told)

Comment: I'm sorry for informal explanation, but I found it hard to put in formal words. My main issue is, why aren't we adding zero in the last step shown in the picture.

Comment: 328=328.000000...

Comment: "why aren't we adding zero in the last step shown in the picture" because first we need to take 35 from 40 and get 5, then extend it to 50 then see 7 goes in 7 times, so we take away 49 etc etc

Comment: I would call it "Long Division".