# Why the Euclidean division of polynomials works?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Why the Euclidean division of polynomials way actually works?

What is the deep insight behind it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Suppose we are working over a field (say the reals, or rationals). We are attempting to divide $A(x)$ by $P(x)$. If the degree of $A$ is equal or bigger than the degree of $P$, then by subtracting a suitable multiple of $P(x)$ we can always lower the degree of $A$ by at least $1$. So the process must terminate.

Comment: Check [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain)'s page on Euclidean domains. The ring of polynomials $\mathbb R[x]$ is a Euclidean domain with as Euclidean function $f(p(x))$ the degree of the polynomial $p$. The Euclidean algorithm works on Euclidean domains.

Comment: Huh? What's that field, ring stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key idea of the polynomial division algorithm is this: if the leading coefficient of the divisor $= 1$ ([or is invertible](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/48963/242)), and the dividend has degree $\ge$ the divisor, then we can  $\rm\color{#c00}{scale}$ the divisor so that it has the same degree and leading coef as the dividend, then subtract it from the dividend, thereby canceling the leading term of the dividend; then recursively apply this process to the remaining part of the dividend, which has *smaller degree* (since we killed the leading term of the dividend), viz.

$$  (\overbrace{a x^{k+n} + f}^{\rm dividend}) - \color{#c00}{a x^k} (\overbrace{x^n + g}^{\rm divisor})\ =\ f-ax^kg$$

$$\ \Rightarrow\ \dfrac{a x^{k+n}+f}{x^n+g}\, =\ \color{#c00}{a x^k} +\!\!\! \underbrace{\dfrac{f-ax^k g}{x^n + g}}_{\large\rm recurse\ on\ this}$$

where the second equation arises from the first by dividing through by $\,x^n + g.\,$ The long division algorithm for polynomials is simply a convenient tabular arrangement of the process obtained by iterating this descent process till one reaches a dividend having smaller degree than the divisor.

**Remark** $\ $ If one seeks a deeper understanding one can view this as a special case of  *multivariate* polynomial division algorithms, such as the  [Gröbner basis algorithm.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grobner_basis) One gains further insight from this more general perspective on the descent process, e.g. in terms of [monomial orderings.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial_order)

Comment: This is why polynomial division works!

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/48963/242) for more.