# For all $f(x)∈R[x]$ and $G(x)∈R[x]$, there exists $q(x)∈R[x]$ such that $f(x)＝G(x)q(x)+P(x)$ such that $\deg P(x)＜\deg G(x)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $R$ be a local ring, $K＝\mathrm{Frac}(R)$.
Let $g(x)∈R[x]$ be polynomial **whose highest coefficient is a unit**.

How can I take $q(x)∈R[x]$ (not from $K[x]$) which satisfies the following

> For all $f(x)∈R[x]$ and $G(x)∈R[x]$, there exists $q(x)∈R[x]$
> such that $f(x)＝G(x)q(x) +P(x)$ such that $\deg P(x)＜\deg G(x)$.

We can take $q(x)∈K[x]$ because $K[x]$ is euclidean, but how can we take from $R[x]$ ?

Background:
This is from Neukirch 'Algebraic number theory', p.130. I don't know how to take 7th line from the bottom, I don't understand why $q(x)∈O[x]$. So I asked this question.

Comment: [Does this answer your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2140378/division-algorithm-for-polynomials-in-rx-where-r-is-a-commutative-ring-with-u)?

Comment: What is Frac(R)? As far as I can see R is not assumed a domain.

Comment: Use induction on deg  (F).

Comment: Basically the same proof as the usual Euclidean algorithm, noting that we only need the leading coefficient of $g(x)$ to be nonzero. As pointed out you don't necessarily have Frac$(R)$, but that is not a problem.

Comment: See the linked dupe - the division algorithm works for any polynomial with unit lead coef $\,u\,$  over any commutative ring. Or we can reduce to the monic case, i.e. divide $f$ by the monic $\,u^{-1} g\,$ so $\,f = q(u^{-1}g) + r = (qu^{-1}) g + r\ \ $