Let $p(x)$ be in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. We know It can be factored as $p(x) = (x-1)(x-2)(x-3)s(x)$. Can I be sure that $s(x)$ is in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ too?
I know a theorem which states: if $p(x)$ has integer coefficients and can be factored in $2$ polynomials with rational coefficients, than It can also be factored in $2$ polynomials with integer coefficients. But I can't answer this question.

The answer is yes because it’s a polynomial division with monic divisor.

As mentioned above, with monic polynomial divisors, the usual polynomial long division algorithm works just fine, and needs only additions / subtractions and multiplications, hence never generates a non-integer coefficient.

P.S.: You may also want to check https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2140378/division-algorithm-for-polynomials-in-rx-where-r-is-a-commutative-ring-with-u?rq=1 and the like.

Thank you, you cleared all my doubts.
